SPSS: related-samples friedman's two-way analysis of variance by ranks extra bar in graph
I'm new here, and somewhat of a lay-user in terms of statistics, and hoping this question will be at the appropriate place.
I'm running the mentioned analysis in SPSS on 3 iterations of an experiment I ran.
Most compared metrics are shown in graphs similar to this, with the expected ranking across the 3 iterations.

However, in some cases, for some metrics, I'm getting graphs that show 4 bars instead of the expected 3.

As I can't find any information regarding this, I'm hoping someone can help me understand what this means/represents.
Many thanks.

Questions primarily about software are usually off-topic here. Even if this is essentially statistical, it makes little sense without some detail on your data and on exactly what you're trying to do. The second graph shows 5 bars in each panel, not 4.

It looks like you have some error in how you are coding rank, or how SPSS is doing that. As Nick mentioned, the bottom graph shows five ranks, not four. Also, the top graphs show four, not three.
Further, in the bottom graph, there is one rank of 2.5, which is odd, not only because it is the only one, but because I think rank here is supposed to be an integer.
So, I would look a) For SPSS documentation on Friedman's test and b) At what data that is using to do this.
This question  might get closed because it's about software. You might try asking on a list devoted to SPSS.
